# Google analytics not tracking outbound links

Tags: google-analytics

I've got the following code in the [head](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) which isn't tracking outbound links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>


<script>
/**
* Function that tracks a click on an outbound link in Google Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label.
*/
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

And have added the event tracking on outbound links as stated on the analytics site:

```
onclick="trackOutboundLink('/WEBSITE/www.something.com')
```

What am I doing wrong? No outbound links are being tracked.

Update - changed the tracking code to universal; which event outbound tracking do I use?

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxx-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**uname12**, the issue is that you are mixing "old" Google Analytics tracking code and "new" Universal Analytics tracking code syntax.

**UPDATE to my original answer to reflect changes to original question:**

I would try using the correct address, so instead of:

```
onclick="trackOutboundLink('/WEBSITE/www.something.com')
```

try this:

```
onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.something.com')
```

**ORIGINAL answer:**

That's the reason why the tracking doesn't work. Here is the [correct documentation for event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) (always look GA.js).

If you change your code to something like this:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {

      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound', 'Click', this.href]);
      setTimeout('document.location = "' + this.href + '"', 100);
      return false;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: If you are implementing Analytics for the new web, then go for Universal Analytics - it will save you troubles later and also UA adds lots of functionality. So adding the basic tracking (see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) will work with the original code you posted.